# Estimating a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

I'm trying to estimate a multivariate normal distribution using a training set of 10.000 examples with 50 features. The observations belong only to 2 classes. I am using a subset of [this dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00199/).

After calculating the mean vector and the covariance matrix for the 2 multivariate normal distributions I get covariances for class0 in the thousands (1.0 e+03) and for class1 ranging in the thousandths (1.0 e-03). Does it have mathematical sense?

The size of the class0 is (7194, 50) and for class1 (2806, 50).

Comment: I don't see any reason (mathematical or otherwise) such that you couldn't have two classes where one is more spread out than the other, even by orders of magnitudes. One possible common-sense check that your code didn't go awry is to simply get means & ranges for each class for each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Converting comment to answer.*)

I don't see any reason (mathematical or otherwise) such that you couldn't have two classes where one is more spread out than the other, even by several orders of magnitude.  One possible common-sense check that your code didn't go awry is to simply get means & ranges for each class for each variable.